# What's the difference between parallel cost and parallel work?

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I read a paper in which **parallel cost** for (parallel) algorithms is defined as C<sub>P</sub>(n) = p * T<sub>P</sub>(n), where `p` is the number of processors, `T` the processing time and `n` the input. An algorithm is *cost-optimal*, if C<sub>P</sub>(n) is approximately constant, i.e. if the algorithm uses two processors instead of one on the same input it takes only half the time.

There is another concept called **parallel work**, which I don't fully grasp.
The papers says it measures the number of executed parallel OPs.
A algorithm is *work-optimal*, if it performs as many OPs as it sequential counterpart (asymptotically). A *cost-optimal* algorithm is always *work-optimal* but not vice versa.

Can someone illustrate the concept of **parallel work** and show the similarities and differences to **parallel cost**?

Comment: It would be helpful to actually give a link to the paper for additional context.

Comment: You can trivially "parallelise" any sequential algorithm by running it on one processor and leaving all other processors idle.  This is work-optimal, but its parallel cost is worse than the original sequential algorithm by a factor equal to the number of processors.

Comment: @b4hand it's a private script from a lecture, so I guess I shouldn't publish it.

Comment: It looks that what the author mean by it is that the paralysation of your algorithm comes without any extra cost. Which is not always true for instance some of them need extra house keeping, if they don't then it is trivial to show that the time is optimal, if not then it still can be cost optimal (approximation may go close to the time you wanted)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers. I have a better understanding now and added an own, detailled answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like parallel work is simply a measure of the total number of instructions ran by all processes in parallel but counting the ones in parallel only once. If that's the case, then it's more closely related to the time term in your parallel cost equation. Think of it this way: if the parallel version of the algorithm runs more instructions than the sequential version --meaning it is *not* work-optimal, it will necessarily take more time assuming all instructions are equal in duration. Typically these extra instructions are at the beginning or end of the parallel algorithm and are viewed as overhead of the parallel algorithm. They can correspond to extra bookkeeping or communication or final aggregation of the result.

Thus an algorithm that is not work-optimal cannot be cost-optimal.

Comment: If the parallel version performs more operations, but makes better use of the cache, it still can be *cost-optimal*, but wouldn't be *work-optimal*, since it performs more instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to call the "parallel cost" is "cost of context switching" although it can also arise from interdependencies between the different threads.

Consider sorting.

If you implement [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) in parallel where each thread just picks up the next comparison you will have a huge cost to run it in "parallel", to the point where it will be essentially a messed up sequential version of the algorithm and your parallel work will be essentially zero because most threads just wait most of the time.

Now compare that to [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and implement a thread for each split of the original array - threads don't need data from other threads, and *asymptotically* for a bigger starting arrays the cost of spinning these threads will be paid by the parallel nature of the work done... if the system has infinite memory bandwidth. In reality it wouldn't be worth spinning more threads than there are memory access channels because the threads still have the invisible (from code perspective) dependency between them by having shared sequential access to memory

Answer (score 1):

### Short

I think **parallel cost** and **parallel work** are two sides of the same coin. They're both measures for speed-up,
whereby the latter is the theoretical concept enabling the former.

### Long

Let's consider n-dimensional vector addition as a problem that is easy to parallelize, since it can be broken down into *n* independent tasks.

[image: Standard vector addition of two n-dimensional vectors a and b resulting in c]

The problem is inherently *work-optimal*, because the **parallel work** doesn't change if the algorithm runs in parallel, there are always *n* vector components that need to be added.

Considering the **parallel cost** cannot be done without executing the algorithm on a (virtual) machine, where practical limitations like shortage of memory bandwidth arise. Thus a *work-optimal* algorithm can only be *cost-optimal* if the hardware (or the hardware access patterns) allows the perfect execution and division of the problem - and the time.

*Cost-optimality* is a stronger demand, and as I'm realizing now, just another illustration of [efficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup#Additional_Details)

[image]

Under normal circumstances a *cost-optimal* algorithm will also be *work-optimal*,
but if the speed-up gained by caching, memory access patterns etc. is super-linear,
i.e. the execution times with two processors is one-tenth instead of the expected half, it is possible for an algorithm that performs more work, and thus is not *work-optimal*, to still be *cost-optimal*.